# TypeError: start_new_game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_health'

Tags: python, typeerror, arcade, positional-argument

So I have been trying to figure out why I keep getting this error, even though everything is run from my game_view.py module. Everytime I press the 1 key to start a game and test to see if the players health bar and hit points works, I get this error message. TypeError: start_new_game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_health'

The sad part is, is that it reffers me to the start_view which doesn't have anything to do with anything else but running the start screen so players can choose to play solo or with another player. Below is the game_view and start_view so you guys can see where I'm going wrong. I wanted to test this out so this way I can add other enemies, bosses and power-ups later, but running into this error for the past several days is hindering progress. Anyway, code for both will be below. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

```
start_view:
import arcade
from game_view import GameView


class StartView(arcade.View):
    def on_show(self):
        # This is run once when we switch to this view
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.csscolor.BLACK)
        # Reset the viewport, necessary if we have a scrolling game
        arcade.set_viewport(0, self.window.width, 0, self.window.height)

    def on_draw(self):
        # Draw this view
        arcade.start_render()
        line_height = 70
        line_location = self.window.height - line_height * 2
        arcade.draw_text("Space Defense Force",
                         self.window.width / 2,
                         line_location,
                         arcade.color.WHITE,
                         font_size=50,
                         anchor_x="center",
                         font_name="SF Atarian System")
        line_location -= line_height
        line_location -= line_height
        arcade.draw_text("1 - Start One Player Game",
                         self.window.width / 2,
                         line_location,
                         arcade.color.WHITE,
                         font_size=20,
                         anchor_x="center",
                         font_name="SF Atarian System")
#         if len(self.window.joysticks) > 1:
#             color = arcade.color.WHITE
#         else:
#             color = arcade.color.GRAY
        color = arcade.color.GRAY
        line_location -= line_height
        arcade.draw_text("2 - Start Two Player Game",
                         self.window.width / 2,
                         line_location,
                         color,
                         font_size=20,
                         anchor_x="center",
                         font_name="SF Atarian System")
        line_location -= line_height
        line_location -= line_height
        color = arcade.color.WHITE
        arcade.draw_text("Use joysticks to play, or arrow keys to move and number keys to fire.",
                         self.window.width / 2,
                         line_location,
                         color,
                         font_size=20,
                         anchor_x="center",
                         font_name="SF Atarian System")
    def on_key_press(self, symbol: int, modifiers: int):
        if symbol == arcade.key.KEY_1:
            game_view = GameView()
            game_view.start_new_game(1)
            self.window.show_view(game_view)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_2:
            game_view = GameView()
            game_view.start_new_game(2)
            self.window.show_view(game_view)

game_view:
import random
import math
import arcade

from health import Health
from game_over_view import GameOverView
from typing import cast
from arcade.experimental.shadertoy import Shadertoy
from constants import *
from asteroid_sprite import AsteroidSprite
from ship_sprite import ShipSprite
from bullet import Bullet
from glow_line import GlowLine
from glow_ball import GlowBall
from explosion import ExplosionMaker
from glow_image_sprite import GlowImageSprite
from window import Window as window

class GameView(arcade.View):
    # Main application class
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Sprite lists
        self.player_sprite_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.asteroid_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.ship_life_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.health_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        
        # Sounds
        self.laser_sound = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/hurt5.wav")
        self.hit_sound1 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/explosion1.wav")
        self.hit_sound2 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/explosion2.wav")
        self.hit_sound3 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/hit1.wav")
        self.hit_sound4 = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/hit2.wav")
        self.dead_sound = arcade.load_sound(":resources:sounds/gameover2.wav")
        self.glowball_shadertoy = Shadertoy.create_from_file(self.window.get_size(), "glow_ball.glsl")
        self.glowline_shadertoy = Shadertoy.create_from_file(self.window.get_size(), "glow_line.glsl")
        self.explosion_list = []
#         for joystick in self.window.joysticks:
#             joystick.push_handlers(self)

    def start_new_game(self, player_count, max_health):
        #Set up the game and initialize the variables
        self.game_over = False
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.csscolor.BLACK)
        # Sprite lists
        self.player_sprite_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.asteroid_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.ship_life_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.health_list = arcade.SpriteList()
#         if len(self.window.joysticks) > 0:
#             joystick = self.window.joysticks[0]
#         else:
#             joystick = None
        joystick = None
        player_sprite = ShipSprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/playerShip1_orange.png",
                                   SCALE,
                                   joystick,
                                   player_no=1,
                                   player_count=player_count,
                                   max_health=5)
        self.player_sprite_list.append(player_sprite)
        self.health_list.append(max_health)
        if player_count > 1:
            joystick = None
#             if len(self.window.joysticks) > 1:
#                 joystick = self.window.joysticks[1]
#             else:
#                 joystick = None
            player_sprite = ShipSprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/playerShip1_green.png",
                                       SCALE,
                                       joystick,
                                       player_no=2,
                                       player_count=player_count,
                                       max_health=5
                                       )
            self.player_sprite_list.append(player_sprite)
            self.health_list.append(max_health)
        # Set up the player
        for player in self.player_sprite_list:
            player.score = 0
            player.lives = 3
            
        # Set up the little icons that represent the player lives.
        cur_pos = 10
        for i in range(self.player_sprite_list[0].lives):
            life = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/playerLife1_orange.png", SCALE)
            life.center_x = cur_pos + life.width
            life.center_y = life.height
            cur_pos += life.width
            self.ship_life_list.append(life)
        if len(self.player_sprite_list) > 1:
            cur_pos = 100
            for i in range(self.player_sprite_list[1].lives):
                life = arcade.Sprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/playerLife1_green.png", SCALE)
                life.center_x = cur_pos + life.width
                life.center_y = life.height
                cur_pos += life.width
                self.ship_life_list.append(life)
                
        # Make the asteroids
        image_list = (":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_big1.png",
                      ":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_big2.png",
                      ":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_big3.png",
                      ":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_big4.png")
        for i in range(STARTING_ASTEROID_COUNT):
            image_no = random.randrange(4)
            enemy_sprite = AsteroidSprite(image_list[image_no], SCALE)
            enemy_sprite.guid = "Asteroid"
            enemy_sprite.center_y = random.randrange(BOTTOM_LIMIT, TOP_LIMIT)
            enemy_sprite.center_x = random.randrange(LEFT_LIMIT, RIGHT_LIMIT)
            enemy_sprite.change_x = random.random() * 2 - 1
            enemy_sprite.change_y = random.random() * 2 - 1
            enemy_sprite.change_angle = (random.random() - 0.5) * 2
            enemy_sprite.size = 4
            self.asteroid_list.append(enemy_sprite)
            
    def on_draw(self):
        # Render the screen.
        # This command has to happen before we start drawing
        arcade.start_render()
        # Draw all the sprites.
        self.asteroid_list.draw()
        self.ship_life_list.draw()
        for bullet in self.bullet_list:
            bullet.draw()
        self.bullet_list.draw()
        for explosion in self.explosion_list:
            explosion.render()
        self.player_sprite_list.draw()
        self.health_list.draw()
        # Put the text on the screen.
        output = f"Player 1 Score: {self.player_sprite_list[0].score}"
        arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 40, arcade.color.AMBER,
                         font_size=15,
                         font_name="Arcade")
        if len(self.player_sprite_list) > 1:
            output = f"Player 2 Score: {self.player_sprite_list[1].score}"
            arcade.draw_text(output, 500, 40, arcade.color.AMBER,
                             font_size=15,
                             font_name="Arcade")
        output = f"Asteroid Count: {len(self.asteroid_list)}"
        arcade.draw_text(output, 10, 80, arcade.color.AMBER,
                         font_size=15,
                         font_name="Arcade")
        for player in health_list:
            player.draw_health_number()
            player.draw_health_bar()
#     def on_joybutton_press(self, joystick, button):
#         # What player is this?
#         if joystick == self.window.joysticks[0]:
#             player_sprite = self.player_sprite_list[0]
#         else:
#             player_sprite = self.player_sprite_list[1]
#         if player_sprite.player_no == 1:
#             color = 255, 128, 128
#         else:
#             color = 128, 255, 128
#         if button == 0:
#             self.fire_circle(color, player_sprite, player_no=player_sprite.player_no)
#         elif button == 1:
#             self.fire_line(color, player_sprite, player_no=player_sprite.player_no)
#         elif button == 2:
#             bullet_sprite = GlowImageSprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/laserBlue01.png",
#                                             SCALE,
#                                             glowcolor=arcade.color.WHITE,
#                                             shadertoy=self.glowball_shadertoy,
#                                             player_no=player_sprite.player_no)
#             self.set_bullet_vector(bullet_sprite, 10, player_sprite)
#             arcade.play_sound(self.laser_sound)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        # Shoot if the player hit the space bar and we aren't respawning.
        if symbol == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].change_angle = 3
        elif symbol == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].change_angle = -3
        elif symbol == arcade.key.UP:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].thrust = 0.15
        elif symbol == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].thrust = -.2
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_1:
            color = (255, 128, 128)
            self.fire_circle(color, self.player_sprite_list[0], player_no=0)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_2:
            color = (128, 255, 128)
            self.fire_circle(color, self.player_sprite_list[0], player_no=0)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_3:
            color = (128, 128, 255)
            self.fire_circle(color, self.player_sprite_list[0], player_no=0)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_4:
            color = (255, 128, 255)
            self.fire_circle(color, self.player_sprite_list[0], player_no=0)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_5:
            color = (255, 255, 255)
            self.fire_line(color, self.player_sprite_list[0], player_no=0)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_6:
            color = (64, 255, 64)
            self.fire_line(color, self.player_sprite_list[0], player_no=0)
        elif symbol == arcade.key.KEY_7:
            bullet_sprite = GlowImageSprite(":resources:images/space_shooter/laserBlue01.png",
                                            SCALE,
                                            glowcolor=arcade.color.WHITE,
                                            shadertoy=self.glowball_shadertoy,
                                            player_no=0)
            self.set_bullet_vector(bullet_sprite, 13, self.player_sprite_list[0])
            arcade.play_sound(self.laser_sound)
            
    def fire_circle(self, bullet_color, player_sprite, player_no):
        bullet_sprite = GlowBall(glowcolor=bullet_color,
                                 radius=5,
                                 shadertoy=self.glowball_shadertoy,
                                 player_no=player_no)
        self.set_bullet_vector(bullet_sprite, 5, player_sprite)
        arcade.play_sound(self.laser_sound)
        
    def fire_line(self, bullet_color, player_sprite, player_no):
        bullet_sprite = GlowLine(glowcolor=bullet_color,
                                 shadertoy=self.glowline_shadertoy,
                                 player=player_sprite,
                                 player_no=player_no)
        self.set_bullet_vector(bullet_sprite, 13, player_sprite)
        arcade.play_sound(self.laser_sound)
        
    def set_bullet_vector(self, bullet_sprite, bullet_speed, player_sprite):
        bullet_sprite.change_y = \
            math.cos(math.radians(player_sprite.angle)) * bullet_speed
        bullet_sprite.change_x = \
            -math.sin(math.radians(player_sprite.angle)) \
            * bullet_speed
        bullet_sprite.center_x = player_sprite.center_x
        bullet_sprite.center_y = player_sprite.center_y
        self.bullet_list.append(bullet_sprite)
        
    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        # Called whenever a key is released
        if symbol == arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].change_angle = 0
        elif symbol == arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].change_angle = 0
        elif symbol == arcade.key.UP:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].thrust = 0
        elif symbol == arcade.key.DOWN:
            self.player_sprite_list[0].thrust = 0
            
    def split_asteroid(self, asteroid: AsteroidSprite):
        # Split an asteroid into chunks
        x = asteroid.center_x
        y = asteroid.center_y
        if asteroid.size == 4:
            for i in range(3):
                image_no = random.randrange(2)
                image_list = [":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_med1.png",
                              ":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_med2.png"]
                enemy_sprite = AsteroidSprite(image_list[image_no],
                                              SCALE * 1.5)
                enemy_sprite.center_y = y
                enemy_sprite.center_x = x
                enemy_sprite.change_x = random.random() * 2.5 - 1.25
                enemy_sprite.change_y = random.random() * 2.5 - 1.25
                enemy_sprite.change_angle = (random.random() - 0.5) * 2
                enemy_sprite.size = 3
                self.asteroid_list.append(enemy_sprite)
                self.hit_sound1.play()
        elif asteroid.size == 3:
            for i in range(3):
                image_no = random.randrange(2)
                image_list = [":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_small1.png",
                              ":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_small2.png"]
                enemy_sprite = AsteroidSprite(image_list[image_no],
                                              SCALE * 1.5)
                enemy_sprite.center_y = y
                enemy_sprite.center_x = x
                enemy_sprite.change_x = random.random() * 3 - 1.5
                enemy_sprite.change_y = random.random() * 3 - 1.5
                enemy_sprite.change_angle = (random.random() - 0.5) * 2
                enemy_sprite.size = 2
                self.asteroid_list.append(enemy_sprite)
                self.hit_sound2.play()
        elif asteroid.size == 2:
            for i in range(3):
                image_no = random.randrange(2)
                image_list = [":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_tiny1.png",
                              ":resources:images/space_shooter/meteorGrey_tiny2.png"]
                enemy_sprite = AsteroidSprite(image_list[image_no],
                                              SCALE * 1.5)
                enemy_sprite.center_y = y
                enemy_sprite.center_x = x
                enemy_sprite.change_x = random.random() * 3.5 - 1.75
                enemy_sprite.change_y = random.random() * 3.5 - 1.75
                enemy_sprite.change_angle = (random.random() - 0.5) * 2
                enemy_sprite.size = 1
                self.asteroid_list.append(enemy_sprite)
                self.hit_sound3.play()
        elif asteroid.size == 1:
            self.hit_sound4.play()
            
    def on_update(self, x, delta_time):
        # Move everything
        self.asteroid_list.update()
        self.bullet_list.update()
        self.player_sprite_list.update()
        self.health_list.update()
        explosion_list_copy = self.explosion_list.copy()
        for explosion in explosion_list_copy:
            explosion.update(x)
            if explosion.time > .9:
                self.explosion_list.remove(explosion)
                
        for bullet in self.bullet_list:
            hit_list = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(bullet, self.player_sprite_list)
            # If it did hit, get rid of sprite
            if len(hit_list) > 0:
                bullet.remove_from_lists()
                
            for player in hit_list:
                if not isinstance(player, ShipSprite):
                    raise TypeError("List contents must be all ints")
                # Remove one health point
                player.cur_health -= 1
                # Check Health
                if player.cur_health <= 0:
                    arcade.play_sound(self.dead_sound)
                    view=GameOverView
                    self.window.show_view(view)
                else:
                    # Not Dead
                    arcade.play_sound(self.hit_sound1)
                    
            assert isinstance(bullet, Bullet)
            asteroids = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(bullet, self.asteroid_list)
            if len(asteroids) > 0:
                explosion = ExplosionMaker(self.window.get_size(), bullet.position)
                self.explosion_list.append(explosion)
            for asteroid in asteroids:
                assert isinstance(asteroid, AsteroidSprite)
                self.player_sprite_list[bullet.player_no - 1].score += 1
                self.split_asteroid(cast(AsteroidSprite, asteroid))  # expected AsteroidSprite, got Sprite instead
                asteroid.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                
            # Remove bullet if it goes off-screen
            size = max(bullet.width, bullet.height)
            if bullet.center_x < 0 - size:
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
            if bullet.center_x > SCREEN_WIDTH + size:
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
            if bullet.center_y < 0 - size:
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
            if bullet.center_y > SCREEN_HEIGHT + size:
                bullet.remove_from_sprite_lists()
                
        for player in self.player_sprite_list:
            assert isinstance(player, ShipSprite, max_health)
            if not player.respawning:
                asteroids = arcade.check_for_collision_with_list(player, self.asteroid_list)
                if len(asteroids) > 0:
                    if player.lives > 0:
                        player.lives -= 1
                        player.respawn()
                        self.split_asteroid(cast(AsteroidSprite, asteroids[0]))
                        asteroids[0].remove_from_sprite_lists()
                        self.ship_life_list.pop().remove_from_sprite_lists()
                elif len(asteroids) > 0:
                    if player.health > 0:
                        player.health -=1
                        player.respawn()
                        self.split_asteroid(cast(AsteroidSprite, asteroids[0]))
                        asteroids[0].remove_from_sprite_lists()
                        self.ship_list_list.pop().remove_from_sprite_lists()
                    else:
                        arcade.play_sound(self.dead_sound)
                        view = GameOverView()
                        self.window.show_view(view)
```

Sorry in advance if I have tons of code to go through. But like I said I am adding some features that wasn't in the Arcade Repository from github. I even set a separte module for the health bar and hit points so this way I can see what conflicts. But the error above has been a royal pain.Thanks again.

P.S. Remarked out joysticks because it was conflicting with another module I built.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Sorry in advance if I have tons of code to go through. " Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The most important way to understand why an error happens is by elimination of all the things that you know *aren't* the cause.

Comment: That said, you should start by looking at how `start_new_game` is defined, and how it is called. For example: Where you have written `def start_new_game(self, player_count, max_health):`, what does that tell you about the information that you need in order to call the function? Where you have written `game_view.start_new_game(1)`, what do you think the `1` means? What do you think the value of `player_count` will be? What do you think the value of `max_health` will be? Why? Do you see how this relates to the error message?

Comment: There is _so much_ unrelated code. The relevant parts of the code are the lines indicated in the error message (which, for this type of error, includes how you call `start_new_game`) and the definition of `start_new_game`. Those are the only things you need to post, how you call it and how it's supposed to be called.

Comment: thanks guys, I'll review all the arguments and keep you posted if I get things working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your title says, your start game function requires 2 arguments: `player_count` and `max_healh`. And in your code, when using `start_new_game`, you aren't supplying the `max_health` argument, thus raising an error.

```py
(function) start_new_game(self, player_count, max_health)
```

Comment: so should I remove 'max_health'  from start_new_game entry? or should I supply the argument somewhere in the code within game_view itself? Bare in mind I am still learning how to work things out with adding new stuff. :) Thanks mate.

Comment: Could a mod close this. I rectified the issue and have supplied the argument for max_health in start_new_game. Thanks!